# how to get a newline in \fbox?

Tags: line-breaking, boxes

I am trying to have two lines in inside `\fbox` but is not working. Below is my code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{vietnam}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Exhaustive Search}
{\centering\fbox{ One billion searches per second $\Rightarrow 36 yrs \newline All this to recover only $10$ bits !}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A `\fbox` doesn't admit line breaks. You have, however, several posiibilities:

Use a `\parbox` (or a `minipage`) inside the `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{vietnam}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Exhaustive Search}
\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{\centering One billion searches per second $\Rightarrow$ 36 yrs  \\ All this to recover only $10$ bits !}}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Inside the `\fbox`, Use a `varwidth` environment from the `varwidth` package if you want the width to adjust automatically:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{vietnam}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\fbox{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
\centering
One billion searches per second $\Rightarrow$ 36 yrs  \\ All this to recover only $10$ bits !
\end{varwidth}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or use a box defined using `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{vietnam}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{fitting}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Exhaustive Search}
\begin{tcolorbox}[minipage,colback=white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt]
\centering
One billion searches per second $\Rightarrow$ 36 yrs \\ All this to recover only $10$ bits !
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a TikZ `\node` with the `align` key:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{vietnam}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Exhaustive Search}
\centering
\tikz
  \node[draw,align=center]
  {One billion searches per second $\Rightarrow$ 36 yrs \\ All this to recover only $10$ bits !};
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or...

Comment: All your solutions are great. However, I am observing something strange in my document. The first time I use any of your solution, it works perfectly. But next time the box, itself, does not appear to be in the middle of slide. In fact it is shifted to the left side of slide. I have added my screen shot in original question

Comment: @NAASI your description is not enough. We need to see the actual code you are using to diagnose the problem and find a solution. Please consider opening a fresh new question.

Comment: Its the first \centering command that is not working properly

Comment: @NAASI Code, please. Without it we can only guess.

Comment: my code is visible in the snap shot that i have added. Its same as yours in solution 2. As per your suggestion, I have posted a new question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259273/centering-not-working-properly

Comment: @NAASI Ah, I hadn't seen your new question. Sorry. However, snapshots are almost useless; please provide the actual code in the form of a MWE.

Comment: How can I make a heading above the box in the 2nd example? maybe with colored background.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to insert manual line-breaks, you might as well construct a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Exhaustive Search}
  \centering
  \fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    One billion searches per second $\Rightarrow 36$ yrs \\
    All this to recover only $10$ bits !
  \end{tabular}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

...or using a pure `tabular` approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Exhaustive Search}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    One billion searches per second $\Rightarrow 36$ yrs \\
    All this to recover only $10$ bits ! \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `\fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}...\\...\end{tabular}}`