# Box fitting content with linebreaks

Tags: box

So I'd like to do something along the line:

```
\mybox{Some content on the first line \\ some content on the second line \\ and this boxes border are fitting the content}
```

So I want a box around content which actually fits the content and also respects things like line breaks. How can I do that?

Comment: Would the content have a fixedwidth, or would the width  be defined through line breaks (i.e. the width would be that of the longest line)?

Comment: Defined by the linebreak but after a lot of googling I just found this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259149/how-to-get-a-newline-in-fbox

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution without any additional packages could use `\fbox` and a
`tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\newcommand\mybox[2][l]{%
  \fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}
\mybox{this text\\is in\\my box\\and the border\\fits}
\mybox[c]{centered text\\is also possible\\with the optional\\argument}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Fixed width is easily possible using `[p{<width>}]` as the optional argument. Right-alignment with `[r]` (since it's a `tabular` any column definition would do).

Comment: see @Werner answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259149/how-to-get-a-newline-in-fbox

Comment: @Zarko didn't see that, I only took a look at the first answer :)

Comment: and how could I add a heading s.t. I can have several boxes next to each other? ( so the heading doesn't distort the floating of the boxes?)

Comment: @xotix That is nothing you requested in your initial question. Take a look at the `tcolorbox` package for fancy boxes with headings and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways: the first uses the `eqparbox` package and an `\fbox` (or, in the following code `\fcolorbox` in case you want some colour), the second, a simple `tabular` with a single centred column, and the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in standard cells.

You also might be interested in the `pbox` package: the eponymous command is like a `\parbox` in which the width argument definas actually a *minimal* width of the box.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\colorlet{framecolor}{Gold}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\newcommand{\myfbox}[1]{\arrayrulecolor{framecolor}\begin{tabular}{|@{\,\,}c@{\,\,}|}
\hline
\makecell[l]{\bigstrut[t]#1 \bigstrut[b]}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\fboxrule = 1pt 
\begin{center}
\fcolorbox{IndianRed}{white}{\eqparbox{mybox}{Some content on the first line \\ some content on the second line \\ and this boxes border are fitting the content.}}
\vskip 1cm

\arrayrulewidth = 1pt
\myfbox{Some content on the first line \\ some content on the second line \\ and this boxes border are fitting the content.}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and how could I make a nice heading? If I have two boxes next to each other (like there's no empty line in the latex file between them) they should align nicely. SO like if there was another box around the main box and its title.

Comment: @xotix:  What you'd to have is not clear to me. You want to put a common heading to two boxes sharing a common horizontal axis?

Comment: No, just a box and a heading. I solved it by using a colorbox around everything now