Aligned TikZ node with label containing a foreach with a newline
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[align=left] {\foreach \i in {1, 2} {hello\\}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This triggers an error:
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\tikz@@align@newline [#1]->\egroup 
                                   \tikz@align@continue \pgfmathparse {#1}\l...

l.6 ...n=left,draw] {\foreach \i in {1, 2} {hello\\}
                                                  };

With an additional text width=10cm (which I do not want), it does not.  Similarly without the align=left (but then the newline has no effect).
Question: Why does it crash?  How should it be written?

a tikz node without a width is an \mbox so can't have \\  if you add width it's a minipage so can.

You need to specify a width to a node (for example with text width=4em) in order to be able to use \\  inside.

@DavidCarlisle and Jasper: I beg to disagree: Without the foreach (e.g., \tikz node[align=left] {hello \\ hello};) works without a problem.  Solutions that use align without a width abound on this very forum (e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/259150/65).  I specifically want the node to be tight around its multiline text.

ah yes foreach groups each iteration you could use a different loop macro

@DavidCarlisle I see, thanks a bunch!  I can now find many times where this has come back to bite users (and many a time where you pointed out that quirk of foreach).  It seems that using \pgfplotsforeachungrouped is a drop-in replacement that doesn't suffer from this.  Summary exploration of the code does not seem to point to a way of replacing \\ with something else while keeping the foreach as is, sadly.

what about...

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[align=left, text width=\linewidth] {\foreach \i in {1, 2} {hello\\}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

